# Can someone explain bizarre rotation of UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I was experimenting with rotating a 320x320 UIView (black) on iPhone containing some CALayers using the following code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    CGAffineTransform rr=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2*2);
    self.transform=rr;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Note that M_PI_2 is pi/2 (math.h). This code rotates the view in place by 180°. However, if I change it to M_PI_2 by itself (no *2), the black UIView vanishes, the contents shift down and to the right and then rotate mostly offscreen. Why is this? I'm stumped as to why the view doesn't just rotate by 90°.

Comment: `M_PI_2*2` is pretty silly, just use `M_PI`.

Comment: Of course, I am messing around with values trying to understand the strange behavior.

Comment: If I change it to     [self.layer setAffineTransform:rr]; then it works. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Because, `transform` is different from `affineTransform`. `transform` expects a `CATransform3D` struct, so you should be using the convenience method `setAffineTransform` instead.

**Edit**

So it seems `self` is an UIView and my above answer is irrelevant. Try using `[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]`.

Comment: Hmm, the uiView.transform is a CGAffineTransform, what you say is true for the layer.transform. Why the difference is strange.

Comment: Oh. If `self` is an UIView then my answer doesn't make sense. I'll update my answer.